What is the relation between the matrix norms $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$?
What is the relation between the matrix norms $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$?
My attempt:-
We know that $\|A\|_{\infty}=\max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|$
$\|A\|_{2}=\max_{\|\vec x\|_2=1} \frac{\|A\vec x\|_2}{\|\vec x\|_2}$
$\|A\|_{2}=\max_{\|\vec x\|_2=1} \frac{\langle Ax, Ax \rangle }{\langle x, x \rangle}.$
I don't know how to proceed.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1154483/42969

They are both norms on a finite dimensional vector space, so we must definitely have the inequality
$$
c_1\| A\|_2 \leq \| A\|_{\infty} \leq c_2 \| A \|_2 
$$
for some positive $c_1, c_2$. We can obtain idea on what these constants might be:
When $\|x\|_2 = 1$, we have that the maximum value for a component of $Ax$ is $|(Ax)_i| = \| A\|_{\infty}$. Thus we get a lower bound for the value of $c_1$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\| A\|_2 &\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |(Ax)_i|^2} \\
&\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \| A\|_{\infty}^2} \\
&= \sqrt{n}\| A\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
Hence $c_1 \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
Now let $A$ be the matrix of ones in the first column and zeros elsewhere. Thus $\| A\|_{\infty} = 1$ and if we let $x=e_1$, then $Ax$ is just the vector with all entries equal to $1$ and we get
\begin{align*}
\|A\|_2 &\geq \| Ax\|_2 \\
&= \sqrt{n} \\
&= \sqrt{n} \| A\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
So we must have that $c_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
A similar idea then works to find the value for $c_2 = \sqrt{n}$
