operator norm in terms of infinity norm
Given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A_{ij}\in[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-1,0]$
What would be the upper bound of operator norm of $A$?

What have you tried?

@Morten I tried to see the relation between the two norms, but didn't obtain result.

Use $|A|2\le\sqrt{|A|1|A|\infty}$ to obtain $|A|2\le n\max{i,j}|a{ij}|$. Equality holds when all elements of $A$ are equal. In your case, the maximum possible value of $|A|_2$ is therefore $n\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

@user1551 Thank you! but my question is about operator norm

the operator norm is the 2 norm...

The operator norm and the infinity norm are the same thing.

@Exodd I believe you are using the notation for the Schatten norms. In which case the two norm is the Hilbert -Schmidt, the one norm is the trace norm and the infinity norm is the operator norm.

Let's make things totally clear: the operator norm is the 2-induced norm and also the infinite-Schatten norm.

Exodd I wrongly refered to you but I meant for @user1151 comment

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154483/show-that-lvert-a-rvert-22-leq-lvert-a-rvert-1-lvert-a-rvert-infty
@lcv  the inequality used by user1551 refers to induced norms, so the 2-norm used by him/her is the operator norm

@Exodd fine. I've never seen the operator norm refered to as the the two norm. I find it confusing but it's fine. $\Vert A\Vert_{2\to2}$ would be another possible notation for the operator norm.
